# Como dar um SELECT em várias base de dados ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho várias bases de dados no meu servidor e preciso realizar uma consulta para retornar algumas informações de uma tabela que existe em todas essas outras bases. Como posso realizar um `SELECT` em várias bases ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Assim que chegar em casa acrescentarei mais informações, se não me engano em bases no mesmo servidor é só remover o servername da consulta e especificar a outra base de dados.

Comment: Tranquilo Dener, agradeço a atenção ai.

Answer (score 9):

Você vai precisar usar `sp_addlinkedserver`, veja a [documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx). Quando o link do servidor estiver estabelecido, poderá construir sua *query*, usando o nome de sua base de dados com outro servidor.

**1° Exemplo** (Consulta com o `INNER JOIN`.):

```
SELECT *
FROM [MinhaBaseDeDadosNoDB1].[dbo].[MinhaTabela] tabela1
    INNER JOIN [DB2].[MinhaBaseDeDadosNoDB2].[dbo].[MinhaOutraTabela] tabela2
        ON tabela1.ID = tabela2.ID
```

**2° Exemplo** (Consulta sem o `INNER JOIN`.):

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    MinhaTabelaLocal,
    [OutroNomeDeServidor].[OutroDB].[dbo].[OutraTabela]
```

Observe que o proprietário não é o `dbo`, você deve substitui-lo com o schema que esta usando.

**3° Exemplo** (Consulta no servidor local.):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [master].[dbo].[spt_values]
```

Onde `master` é a minha base de dados, `dbo` é o meu schema e `spt_values` é a tabela que eu desejo obter informações, não houve a necessidade de usar o comando `user`, é só indicar o caminho completo para a tabela.

Fontes:
[Querying data by joining two tables in two database on different servers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5145685/5429980)
[Selecting data from two different servers in SQL Server.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1144070/5429980)

Comment: Dener, entendi o que você falou, mas acho que me expressei errado. Minhas bases estão no mesmo servidor, uma de baixo da outra no meu Management, mas não posso usar a instrução USE pq uma consulta vai matar a outra, ai não sei qual instrução usar para consultar todas as bases ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: @Marcilhovisck coloquei o outro exemplo.

Comment: Obrigado pelos exemplos Dener, deu uma "clareada" aqui pra mim.

Answer (score 0):

Desta forma funciona. Olhe a legenda.

```
select * from 1.[2].[dbo].3
```

> 1 = servidor
>
> 2 = base
>
> 3 = tabela

#### Ex:

```
select * from srv01.[db_brasil].TB_CIDADES
```