# Criar view com dados de dois Schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

tenho dois bancos de dados e preciso criar uma view no banco1 com dados do banco2
porem não encontro a sintaxe correta para realizar essa operação segue codigo

```
USE banco1
GO
CREATE VIEW TABELA_PROJ_463 as  

USE banco2
go

select * from PROJECAO_RECEB_MENSAL

WHERE CODIGO_GRUPO >= 463
```

Comment: Veja se esta resposta te ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110614/como-dar-um-select-em-v%C3%A1rias-base-de-dados-ao-mesmo-tempo

Comment: obrigado bins, resolveu meu problema !